# Momentum conservation in relativistic collision of identical particles

Tags: special-relativity, mass, collision

In the Feynman Lectures on Physics (Lecture 16, Vol I) there is this example where he considers an elastic collision between two particles with the same initial speed (say $v_0$)

[image]

Considering the symmetry of the situation and the conservation of energy it was pretty self explanatory that the initial and final speeds of the particles remain unchanged.

Now if the situation is viewed from, the frame of reference of another observer travelling rightward with the speed $ v_0 \cos(\theta/2)$ then the situation understandably looks as below from the moving frame:

[image]

The difficulty here is that Feynman later shows the vertical velocities of the two particle to be different as viewed from the moving frame but shouldn't both of them equal 
$v_0 \sin(\theta/2)\sqrt{1 - \frac{(v_0\cos(\theta/2))^2}{c^2}}$ by the relation:

$v_y = v_y^{'}\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}}$     :for a frame moving along the x direction with speed $u$

The obvious difficulty in accepting that the two vertical speeds are equal is that then the momentum would not be conserved when viewing from the moving frame because of the dependence of mass with speeds.

So where am I missing the point.

Comment: Transformation of velocity in special relativity is somewhat different, it depends also on $v_x'$ which is different for the two particles. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now